# ITVF with With-Statement possible?

Tags: sql, t-sql, sql-server-2012

IS it possible to return the table of a With-Statement from an inline-table valued function?

my With-Statement looks like this

```
WITH ret AS(
        SELECT  t.ID
        FROM    SelfReferencingTable
        WHERE   ID = @PartnerID
        UNION ALL
        SELECT  t.ID
        FROM    (SelfReferencingTable) t INNER JOIN
                ret r ON t.ParentID = r.ID
)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can. You just have to place the [common table expression](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190766%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) (what you refer to as a `WITH` statement) in the appropriate place:

```
create function TT()
RETURNS TABLE
AS
    RETURN (With Aardvark as (select * from sysobjects) --TODO - Remove *, use column names
        select * from Aardvark)
;
```